# Show that the map defined by $\sigma(g)$=$p(g^{-1})$ is a representation.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose G is abelian.
Show that the map $\sigma : G -> GL(n,F)$ defined by $\sigma(g)=p(g^{-1})$ for all g in G is a representation of G.

I think I have done this I would just like to check my answer.

So;

$\sigma(gh)=p((gh)^{-1})=p(h^{-1}g^{-1})=p(h^{-1})p(g^{-1})=p(g^{-1})p(h^{-1})=\sigma(g)\sigma(h)$ since G is abelian, therefore it is a representation since $\sigma(gh)=\sigma(g)\sigma(h)$.

Thanks

Comment: You define $\sigma$ using $p$. What is $p$?

Comment: a representation

Comment: Yes. If $\rho:G\to H$ is any homomorphism and $\alpha\in{\rm End}(G)$ an endomorphism, then $\rho\circ\alpha$ is also a homomorphism. This applies here with $H={\rm GL}(n,F)$ and $\alpha:x\mapsto x^{-1}$ (which is an endomorphism, in fact an automorphism, iff $G$ is abelian).

Answer (score 2):

You should mention in the question that $p$ is a representation of $G$.

About your proof, you write a series of $5$ equalities and at the end you write ``since $G$ is abelian..." where exactly did you use the fact that $G$ is abelian?

The argument should go as follows:
$$\sigma(gh)=p((gh)^{-1})=p(h^{-1}g^{-1}){\ \color{red} =\ }p(g^{-1}h^{-1})=p(g^{-1})p(h^{-1})=\sigma(g)\sigma(h).$$

The red ${\color{red}=}$ is where you use the fact that $G$ is abelian. The other equlities follow from the definition of $\sigma$, the fact that the inverse of a product is the product of inverses in reverse order, and the fact that $p$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: thanks, yes that is where I was using the fact G is abelian!

Comment: Note that my red equality is NOT the same as your third equality.